# BertForTokenClassification Not loading

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, load, bert-language-model

I tried to load a Bert model from local directory and it was showing an error
I am using cuda 10.0 version and pytorch 1.6.0

Code to load model:-

```
output_dir = './ner_model/'
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(output_dir)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(output_dir)
model.to(device)
```

Any help would be appreicated

```
ReadError: invalid header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    511             try:
--> 512                 state_dict = torch.load(resolved_archive_file, map_location="cpu")
    513             except Exception:

~\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    385     try:
--> 386         return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    387     finally:

~\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    558                 # .zip is used for torch.jit.save and will throw an un-pickling error here
--> 559                 raise RuntimeError("{} is a zip archive (did you mean to use torch.jit.load()?)".format(f.name))
    560             # if not a tarfile, reset file offset and proceed

RuntimeError: ./ner_model/pytorch_model.bin is a zip archive (did you mean to use torch.jit.load()?)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-770da388c2c8> in <module>
     23 
     24 output_dir = './ner_model/'
---> 25 model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(output_dir)
     26 tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(output_dir)
     27 model.to(device)

~\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    513             except Exception:
    514                 raise OSError(
--> 515                     "Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file. "
    516                     "If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True. "
    517                 )

OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file. If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, pleas
```

e set from_tf=True.

Comment: The error message is quite descriptive here. Did you try to set `from_tf` to `True`?

Comment: Yes I tried but still there is an error saying RuntimeError: ./ner_model/pytorch_model.bin is a zip archive (did you mean to use torch.jit.load()?)